# Problem with \rowcolor and monochrome option

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I have a document that I wish to distribute both in color and monochrome. It contains tables and makes use of colored rows. Problem is, when I use the monochrome option for the `xcolor` package the colored rows show up as completely black and thus cannot be read.

What I would like is for the text to be readable even when the `monochrome` option is active.

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
This & that\\
\rowcolor{yellow} This & that
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(If I remove the `monochrome` option all is well).

Comment: What should happen to a yellow row color if you use `monochrome`? If I use `\textcolor{yellow}{text}` the `text` appears black, too.

Comment: I'd want the colors to become shades of gray. However, on second thought, that's not really monochrome...

Comment: @SašoŽivanović `\usepackage[gray,table]{xcolor}`

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
\makeatletter
\let\CT@@do@color\relax
\makeatother
```

after loading `colortbl` (redefining the internal command rather than `\rowcolor` means that you stop all `colortbl` color commands including use of optional arguments etc.